# Function not functioning properly

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash-cs6

I have a question about my function.
This is my function :

```
function checkKind()
{
    var i:Number = new Number;
    for (i=0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        if (pValue[i] >= 1 && pValue[i] <= 13)
        {
            pKind[i] = 1;
        }
        else if (pValue[i] >= 14 && pValue[i] <= 26)
        {
            pKind[i] = 2;
        }
        else if (pValue[i] >= 27 && pValue[i] <= 39)
        {
            pKind[i] = 3;
        }
        else if (pValue[i] >= 40 && pValue[i] <= 52)
        {
            pKind[i] = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

`pKind[i]` is always filled up with number 1, so `pKind[i] = 1`.
I've already checked the `pValue[i]` which is properly filled.
Can someone help me to see what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Your code looks fine.

Comment: pKind[i] can't filled properly. It's always filled with 1 even if my pValue[i] is correct.

Comment: I checked Your code: https://gist.github.com/subdan/0562d3bba525bdb45e48 As You can see, all is ok. Whats wrong?

Comment: It's better to replace first two lines of "checkKind" function to "for (var i:int = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)"

Comment: @subdan yes, but pKind[i] is not filled with what it should, it's always filled with 1 whatever the pValue[i] is. I will try your advice, i'll tell you if it can solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: Your code is fine, for example `pValue = [1,52,30,12,22,50]` gives `pKind = [1,4,3,1,2,4]`, so could you show your `pValue` array ?

Comment: I don't understand You. I get Your pValue and pKind. New pKind value is [1,4,3,1,2,4,1,1]. https://gist.github.com/subdan/5d0cb59bbc68337aa906

Comment: @subdan Sorry man, my comment was for OP not for you ;)

Comment: @akmozo oops, sorry :)

Comment: Finally i found out what the problem is. I insert wrong variable for my function, it's not the pValue[i] but the other variable. I'm sorry everyone and thanks for trying to help my carelessness.